Amplification Calculation
I have a question about how to calculate the amplification of amplifier.
Here is the circuit:

The equation provided by in the datasheet for calculating the output is:
CURphase = VOFS - amplification * (Rsense * Iphase + Vinofs)
I am questioning is this equation is correct if the output amplifier is set to x2. Since it is amplified after adding the VOFS, which mean the VOFS will be amplify as well, causing the total amplification is not just simple as 10x2 = 20. Is that my concern correct?
Is it the equation should be like this?
CURphase = amplification2 * (VOFS - amplification1 * (Rsense * Iphase + Vinofs))
Thank you!!!

WC_iOS - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the answer & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + PDF title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full details of the source e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More details of site rules are in the [tour] & [help].)

Are you using a TMC6200 Universal high voltage BLDC/PMSM/Servo MOSFET 3-halfbridge gate-driver with in-line motor current sensing. External MOSFETs for up to 100? The datasheet seems to have the same Figure 6.1 Principle of sense amplifier as the picture the question,.
